# VBA - Control chart with upper and lower brackets

Tags: excel

I would like to create a graph as below. I tried using a scatter chart and I ended up like this:

[image]

**But, what I want is this:**

[image]

Where am I going wrong? TIA!

*** UPDATE ***
So, I was able to plot the graph the way I wanted (almost). But, what I am missing is displaying the data points (see the black points in the second picture)

[image]

Comment: @BigBen - Sorry I was not clear with my question. So, let me try and break it down to a couple of questions. 1. How do I set upper and lower bracket to a chart. As you could see from the second example chart, they are plotting the numbers (23, 29, 34 etc.,) on the graph and I believe Excel is translating them to percentages. I guess my question is how does a built in graph do it. Thanks.

Comment: I am checking this YT clip at the moment https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=os17KYZAnd0. But, if you are able to offer a quick solution, I can take that :)

Comment: Ben - Thanks for your recommendations. I pretty much followed the YT clip and I ended up close to where I want to be (see the third picture in the question). However, I want to highlight/display the data points. I am not able to do that right now. Any help there?

Comment: Add data labels or data callouts - right-click the series in the chart.

Comment: Hmm? Where do I find them :) ? I can't find them in the chart options. I am able to "dot" them using the Marker options. But, I want to display the values too.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-data-labels-in-a-chart-884bf2f1-2e29-454e-8b42-f467c9f4eb2d

Comment: Awesome! That did it.